# How to create unmodifiable durable subscriber from .net client for ibm amqp topic?

Tags: .net, ibm-mq, publish-subscribe, amqp

We have a client using .net client to connect to our IBM mq topic over amqp(specified by client).
We have administratively created subscriber. Whenever client connects to our topic via amqp channel using .net client, it modifies either expiry or durable property of subscriber. How should we prevent client from modifying our subscriber.( It specifically creates altogether new subscriber with durable property set to NO)

We don't have access to client code but it is similar to
https://github.com/amqphub/equipage/blob/master/amqpnetlite/Subscriptions/DurableSubscribe/DurableSubscribe.cs

We have created one administrator subscriber which is durable and expiry is unlimited.

```
dis sub(':private:123:TOPIC01')
23 : dis sub(':private:123:TOPIC01')
AMQ8096: WebSphere MQ subscription inquired.
SUBID(xxxxxxx)
SUB(:private:123:TOPIC01') TOPICSTR(TOPIC01)
TOPICOBJ( ) DISTYPE(RESOLVED)
DEST(SYSTEM.MANAGED.DURABLE.xxxxx)
DESTQMGR(xxxxx) PUBAPPID( )
SELECTOR( ) SELTYPE(NONE)
USERDATA( )
PUBACCT(xxxx)
DESTCORL(xxxx)
DESTCLAS(MANAGED) DURABLE(YES)
EXPIRY(UNLIMITED) PSPROP(MSGPROP)
PUBPRTY(ASPUB) REQONLY(NO)
SUBSCOPE(ALL) SUBLEVEL(1)
SUBTYPE(ADMIN) VARUSER(ANY)
WSCHEMA(TOPIC) SUBUSER(mqm)
CRDATE(2020-11-13) CRTIME(12:38:26)
ALTDATE(2020-11-13) ALTTIME(12:38:26)
```

But when client connects to IBM MQ then it modify subscriber .

```
dis sub(':private:123:TOPIC01')
37 : dis sub(':private:123:TOPIC01')
AMQ8096: WebSphere MQ subscription inquired.
SUBID(xxxx)
SUB(:private:123:TOPIC01) TOPICSTR(TOPIC01)
TOPICOBJ(SYSTEM.BASE.TOPIC) DISTYPE(RESOLVED)
DEST(SYSTEM.MANAGED.NDURABLE.xxx)
DESTQMGR(xxxx) PUBAPPID( )
SELECTOR( ) SELTYPE(NONE)
USERDATA(000)
PUBACCT(xxx)
DESTCORL(xxx)
DESTCLAS(MANAGED) DURABLE(NO)
EXPIRY(UNLIMITED) PSPROP(MSGPROP)
PUBPRTY(ASPUB) REQONLY(NO)
SUBSCOPE(ALL) SUBLEVEL(1)
SUBTYPE(API) VARUSER(FIXED)
WSCHEMA(TOPIC) SUBUSER(xxx)
CRDATE(2020-11-13) CRTIME(10:12:39)
ALTDATE(2020-11-13) ALTTIME(10:12:39)
```

Check new subscriber is created with durable set to NO changing from earlier value of YES

Looking for your help

Comment: They look like two different subscriptions. The first one to `TOPIC01` and the second to `SYSTEM.BASE.TOPIC\TOPIC01`. Other than the display, is the first subscriber actually affected? What does display show when the second subscriber stops running?

Comment: @chughts It shows AMQ8464: WebSphere MQ subscription :private:123:TOPIC01 not found. We can see only one subscriber not two.SYSTEM.BASE.TOPIC is the base topic .

Comment: `not found` - so the subscription is removed when the second app stops?